# MySQL Greater Than IN

Tags: mysql, comparison, simplify

Currently I'd have to write a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value1 > 5000 OR value2 > 5000 OR value3 > 5000 OR value4 > 5000
```

As you can see, the 5000 is compared to all of those columns. Ideally, you'd be able to write a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 5000 GREATER(value1,value2,value3,value4)
```

I know you can do

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 5000 IN(value1,value2,value3,value4)
```

But that tests for equality, not greater than.

Is there a way to do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE greatest(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5) > 5000 ;
```

As a note, this is not *exactly* the same.  If any of the values are `NULL` this will return `NULL`, which is treated as false.  The version with `or` will skip `NULL` values.

Comment: Actually @Gordon Linoff, wouldn't it be greatest()? Awesome answer though!

Comment: @Bubby4j . . . Yes.  `least()` would be used for `and`.